# 'this' of type "Class* const" even though method is not const

Tags: c++, constants

Today I noticed something strange about the type of 'this'. If you have something like this:

```
class C {
    void funcA() {
        funcB(this);
    }

    void funcB(C obj) {
        //do something
    }
};
```

You will of course get an error, because funcB() expects an object, while 'this' is a pointer. I accidentally did forget the asterisk, but was surprised by the error message, as it said:

```
no matching function for call to 'C::funcB(C* const)'
```

Where does the const come from, when funcA() is not constant?

Comment: that is right because the this is constant.  you can't, for example, do: this = 0;

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's saying that the `this` pointer *itself* as `const` -- i.e., you can't modify the pointer to point to different memory.

Back in the *very* early history of C++, before you could overload `new` and `delete`, or placement new was invented, `this` was a non-const pointer (at least inside the ctor). A class that wanted to handle its own memory management did so by allocating space for an instance in the constructor, and writing the address of that memory into `this` before exiting the constructor.

In a const member function the type you'd be dealing would be `Class const *const this`, meaning that what `this` points at is `const` (as well as the pointer itself being `const`).

Comment: Technically this is not correct. `this` is not constant pointer, it is an *expression* (*prvalue*) that yields a pointer to the object on which the member method was called. But yes, the implementation is probably creating a constant pointer, and naming it `this`... (although the standard says that the type of the expression `this` is non-const pointer to a possibly const-volatile qualified object)

Answer (score 8):

`C* const` does not mean that the object of type `C` is constant.  That would be `C const*` or `const C*`.

`C* const` means that the pointer itself is constant.

Which makes sense, since you cannot do

```
this = &something_else;
```

Answer (score 4):

Note that it's not `C const *`, but `C* const`. I.e. (reading from right to left) constant pointer to `C`.

Answer (score 4):

There is a difference between `C const*` and `C * const`. You need to understand the difference:

- `C const*` means it is the object (pointed to by the pointer) which is constant.
- `C * const` means it is the pointer itself which is constant.

So `this` by definition is a pointer of `C * const` type, so it cannot be modified, though the object pointed to by it can still be modified.

Answer (score 3):

The pointer itself is constant, not the data pointed to.